# How to enable Google Maps zoom controls using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I was reading the documentation of [Google maps for swift](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/controls) , but compared with Android, I didn't find a way to set the 'Zoom Controls' on my map and by default are disabled.

Exist a way with the `Google Maps iOS SDK` to display the controls?

Comment: I don't think Google Maps for iOS actually has zoom controls. It's all gesture controlled

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think @Scriptable is right, the documentation hasn't a section for `Zoom Controls` for `iOS SDK`.

Well, I made my own (and very basic) controls.
[image]

Keep this order (`MapView`, `Button`, `Button`), else, you can't see the buttons.

[image]

First one, you must select your `UIVIew` and change the class to `GSMMapView`

and, in the `MapViewController`

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    struct Place {
        let id: Int
        let name: String
        let lat: CLLocationDegrees
        let lng: CLLocationDegrees
        let icon: String
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
    var markerDict: [Int: GMSMarker] = [:]

    var zoom: Float = 15

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 34.1381168, longitude: -118.3555723, zoom: zoom)
        self.mapView.camera = camera

        do {
            if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "style", withExtension: "json") {
                mapView.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)
            } else {
                NSLog("Unable to find style.json")
            }
        } catch {
            NSLog("One or more of the map styles failed to load. \(error)")
        }

        let places = [
            Place(id: 0, name: "MrMins", lat: 34.1331168, lng: -118.3550723, icon: "i01"),
        ]

        for place in places {
            let marker = GMSMarker()
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: place.lat, longitude: place.lng)
            marker.title = place.name
            marker.snippet = "Custom snipet message \(place.name)"
            marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
            //marker.icon = self.imageWithImage(image: UIImage(named: place.icon)!, scaledToSize: CGSize(width: 35.0, height: 35.0))
            marker.map = self.mapView

            markerDict[place.id] = marker
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    @IBAction func btnZoomIn(_ sender: Any) {
        zoom = zoom + 1
        self.mapView.animate(toZoom: zoom)
    }

    @IBAction func btnZoomOut(_ sender: Any) {
        zoom = zoom - 1
        self.mapView.animate(toZoom: zoom)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should catch current value of zoom, because If you hardcode zoom value and user will use not only buttons but buttons and gestures when user will pressed on button after zoom out by gestures you will zoom to old zoom value (very close to map)

to fix this moment you should catch zoom value here (in GMSMapViewDelegate)

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {
    zoom = mapView.camera.zoom
}
```

all code will be looks like this

```
    class A: UIViewController {
      var zoom: Float = 15

    @IBAction func ZoomInButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let nextZoom = zoom + 1
        mapView.animate(toZoom: nextZoom)
    }
}

extension A: GMSMapViewDelegate { 
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {
        zoom = mapView.camera.zoom
    }
}
```